# Why won't my Fujifilm X-T2 take pictures when I press the shutter?

Tags: autofocus, troubleshooting, shutter, fujifilm

I'm having a problem with my Fuji X-T2; it doesn't make pictures anymore. When I try to press the shutter, it will focus and it makes the focus sound but then it does nothing when I press the shutter button. I've already looked through the manual but none of the problems listed there seems to be happening. I've already tried a different card and placed it in the other slot but the same thing happens. Also in recording mode or any of the other modes it will only focus but not record/click.

As far as I can recall I didn't change anything in the settings (or at least not on purpose). Yesterday it was still working, then this morning I took the pictures of the SD card on my laptop and now suddenly it doesn't work anymore. I've tried:

- Reformatting the SD card in the camera
- Factory reset on the camera
- Changing the mode dial to all positions

The weird thing is that the camera doesn't give any error message or anything (which I think should be happening if there's a problem with the SD card or battery or something like that). In the picture below I've got the shutter button pressed fully down, you can see it's focused and as far as I can see, nothing is weird?

[image: when camera shutter is pressed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I took the camera to a camera shop and turns out the button is broken! They said it was probably due to wear. So I've sent it back to Fuji and they're repairing it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to check

- Does it have a memory card? While at it also enable the warning for use without memory card in the menu. I do think it does trigger without card though. If it has a card try another card.
- What lens is mounted? For non Fuji lenses you need to enable shooting without lens. Also for use without lens that is (duh). Plus a "broken" not recognized lens can have the same effect without expecting it. Also try another lens.
- Check what the setting is for the trigger button in the custom buttons menu. Not completely sure what the options are but could be that you can disable the shooting part and only use it for focus and then assign shooting to another button. Sounds plausible so just check and you'll know for sure.
- With any of these problems it's always a good idea to perform a factory reset. That way you're sure you disable any of the options you might have set.
- You could also try a firmware update. There was an update that caused some lock up issues in the past. Do this only if all other options failed.

Good luck and make sure to report back what the issue was.